# yocto Qt creator libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: _dl_make_stack_executable, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am trying to build Qt apps for my yocto setup using qt creater, but when I Run Qmake I get this error,
/opt/poky/3.1.28/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qmlcachegen: symbol lookup error: /opt/poky/3.1.28/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/../lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: _dl_make_stack_executable, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

I am using yocto dunfell and qt5, qt creater version is 4.11.0

I could not find the how to resolve this error, I am new to qt and yocto.

I followed the following tutorials as reference to setup yocto and qt, and qt creator,
https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Qt_Creator
https://www.ics.com/blog/configuring-qt-creator-yocto-development

Please help me with this.
Thanks